# Evaluation of bids based on bidders preferences and bid value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access database with details of bidders with their preferences and bid value for several projects. However, I want to select the substantial lowest bidder for a particular project. The evaluation shall be like this

**Project A**

| bidder | bid value | preferences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1500 | 2 |
| BB | 2000 | 1 |
| CC | 4000 | 1 |

**Project B**

| bidder | bid value | preferences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BB | 1000 | 2 |
| CC | 2000 | 4 |
| AA | 2500 | 1 |

**Project C**

| bidder | bid value | preferences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1500 | 5 |
| CC | 2000 | 2 |
| BB | 2500 | 3 |

.....
.....
.....
Continue

Selecting criteria is, after checking minimum qualifications of the bidder, which offers the lowest bid value for each project. If two bidders are offering the same lowest bid value, both should be selected. However, a bidder should be selected for maximum of 5 bids. These 5 bids shall selected based on the bidder's preferences given for each project. If he is selected for next project, his bid shall reject and consider for the next bidder.

So could you please suggest me an algorithm to above criteria for MS Access and VBA.

I have tried in many ways, with each project, and consider the lowest bid with the lowest preferences. However, for selecting the maximum selected bids for a bidder, could not get those according to their preferences given for a project.

Comment: You don't actually have each project in its own table, I hope?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these correlated TOP N subquery SQL structures will get you on the right path. I created a table and records for testing.

| ID | ProjectID | BidderID | Bid | Preferences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1500 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2000 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4000 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 8000 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 2000 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 | 2500 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 | 1500 | 5 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 | 2000 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 | 1 | 2500 | 3 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 | 1500 | 2 |
| 11 | 6 | 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 12 | 6 | 2 | 2500 | 3 |
| 13 | 7 | 1 | 1500 | 4 |
| 14 | 7 | 2 | 1000 | 2 |
| 15 | 8 | 1 | 1000 | 3 |
| 16 | 8 | 2 | 1500 | 5 |

Query1: LowBids

```
SELECT Bids.*
FROM Bids
WHERE (((Bids.[ID]) In (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Bids AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.ProjectID = Bids.ProjectID ORDER BY Dupe.Bid)));
```

Query2:

```
SELECT LowBids.* FROM LowBids WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 5 ID from LowBids AS Dupe 
   WHERE Dupe.BidderID=LowBids.BidderID ORDER BY BidderID, Preferences)
ORDER BY BidderID, Preferences;
```

| ID | ProjectID | BidderID | Bid | Preferences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 6 | 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4000 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1500 | 2 |
| 15 | 8 | 1 | 1000 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 2000 | 4 |
| 14 | 7 | 2 | 1000 | 2 |
| 10 | 5 | 2 | 1500 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks.. how can I get the next bidder for a project when the top bidder reaches for maximum bids?

Comment: Afraid I don't understand that request. What steps would you follow to manually make that determination? Note that project 4 does not have record in the final output. I am thinking SQL alone cannot solve this problem and will require complex VBA procedure, perhaps involving writing records to a 'temp' table. Seems my answer just serves to underscore this and not really offer anything substantial toward resolution. When you have some code with specific issue, post a question. If you can outline the steps to manually determine which records to retrieve, should be able to code the logic.